# How can I show download progress in a dialog box for a file download on browser

Tags: javascript

```
let bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length);
      for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] =data[i];
      }
      let file = new Blob([bytes], { type: "text/xml" });
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
      let fileName = "file.xml";
      link.download = fileName;
      link.click();
      this.openDialog();
```

I want to execute `openDialog()` method once the download is started on the browser.
I tried to display the dialog box after the `link.click()` is executed but if the browsers 'Ask where to save each file before downloading' option is turned on  the dialog box is displayed before the user selects the directory and clicks okay.

Comment: _"but if the browsers 'Ask where to save each file before downloading' option is turned on the dialog box is displayed before the user selects the directory and clicks okay."_ - probably not much you can do about that; that "save as" box it outside of the realm of what you can influence with scripting from the context of your website.

Comment: Not sure what you'd want with that dialog of yours to begin with, what do you mean by "show progress"? You don't get access to anything like a percentage value or number of already received bytes or anything here. So at most you could show me some "download started" message or something - but that is functionality my browser has implemented already anyway.

Comment: You delegate downloading files to the browser. And you have no chance to get more data about it. Using `fetch` also won't help you cause you need to do a lot in order to get the progress of your download. Instead, you can use `axios`. It will help you with what you want.